# Xcode 8.3.3 Bad Syntax Highlighting in C++

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode8, syntax-highlighting

I've noticed some rather peculiar syntax highlighting inconsistencies. The `class`, `if`, `else`, `while` and `break` keywords are not colorized for some reason. This problem persists even after changing color themes and restarting Xcode. I am using the Civic theme which is one of the defaults in Xcode. The problem seems to be language-specific since this only happens for C++ while it doesn't for objective-c or Python.

[image]

Comment: Whats the theme name you are using?

Comment: @AlexG I've updated it above

Comment: Do you have access to the theme file?

Comment: @AlexG yes I do but I don't think there is an upload function in StackOverflow

Comment: https://expirebox.com/

Comment: Something more permanent would be better but at least I can see it then.  Just comment the link.

Comment: https://expirebox.com/download/af7dac564587c38a32a5e8906844ffd1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution which is far from ideal and from the looks of it, it seems to be an Xcode bug.

1. Open the `Preferences` window
2. Go to the `Locations` tab
3. Click on the arrow next to `/Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
4. Go to `User Data`
5. Go to `FontAndColorThemes`
6. Open any `.xccolortheme` file with Xcode

   ```
   <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.class</key>
   <string>0.115602 0.660894 0.635056 1</string>
   <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.class.system</key>
   <string>0.221291 0.537118 0.556094 1</string> # change this line

   <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.function</key>
   <string>0.115602 0.660894 0.635056 1</string>
   <key>xcode.syntax.identifier.function.system</key>
   <string>0.221291 0.537118 0.556094 1</string>
   ```

The color code for the `xcode.syntax.identifier.class.system` was not equivalent to that of `xcode.syntax.identifier.function.system` which caused the `class` keyword to not be colorized. So the solution is to make them the same. Do the same for all the other keywords.

For a reason which I cannot understand, changing that line for a single color theme automatically fixes this bug for all color themes. Also, I've yet to figure out why this bug was language-specific for C++. Nevertheless, the solution works.